# Get notified when NDEF is sent / touch to beam is pressed

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, nfc-p2p, android-beam

I am using `setNdefPushMessageCallback` to send an NDEF message (text/plain) through Android Beam (TM) from one Android device to another one. In `onResume` I am checking `ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED` so in this way the Android phone that is detecting/reciving the message is being notified.

But how can I get notified in the other phone (the one sending the message)? As I can think there should be a way to detect when we touch the screen to beam the message, but I have not seen any constans on `NfcAdapter` that is called for this purpose.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);
}

@Override
public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent nfcEvent) {
    ...
    NdefRecord ndefRecord = NdefRecord.createMime("text/plain", message.getBytes());
    NdefMessage ndefMessage = new NdefMessage(ndefRecord);
    return ndefMessage;

}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Parcelable[] rawMessages = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        NdefMessage message = (NdefMessage) rawMessages[0]; 
        status = new String(message.getRecords()[0].getPayload());
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register an `OnNdefPushCompleteCallback`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mAdapter.setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(this, this);
    mAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);
}

@Override
public void onNdefPushComplete(NfcEvent event) {
    ...
}
```

This callback will be invoked when the message was successfully pushed over Beam.